# I can't hide my scroll bar because of JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html and css file that have no errors. But the problem is that i cant hide my body scroll bar unless i remove jquery. I dont understand the problem here there must be some type of way around this.

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <title>OUZO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo-4.ico">


<script src="jquery.nicescroll.js">
</script>

      <script>

$(document).ready(
function() {
$("#video-wrapper").niceScroll();
$("#news-wrapper").niceScroll();
$("#games-wrapper").niceScroll();
$("#music-wrapper").niceScroll();
}
);
</script>

</head>

<body>

  <nav align="middle">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="videos.html"><img src="images/video-menu.png" class="vid" style="height:35px; width:70px; margin-bottom:20px; border-left:8px solid black; border-right:8px solid black;" onmouseover="this.src='images/video-menu-hover.png'"onmouseout="this.src='images/video-menu.png';"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/news-menu.png" class="news" style="height:35px; width:70px; margin-bottom:20px; border-left:8px solid black; border-right:8px solid black;" onmouseover="this.src='images/news-menu-hover.png'"onmouseout="this.src='images/news-menu.png';"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="home" style="height:80px; width:80px;" onmouseover="this.src='images/logo-hover.png'"onmouseout="this.src='images/logo.png';"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/games-menu.png" class="games" style="height:35px; width:70px; margin-bottom:20px; border-right:8px solid black;border-left:8px solid black;" onmouseover="this.src='images/games-menu-hover.png'"onmouseout="this.src='images/games-menu.png';"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/music-menu.png" class="music" style="height:35px; width:70px; margin-bottom:20px; border-right:8px solid black; border-left:8px solid black;" onmouseover="this.src='images/music-menu-hover.png'"onmouseout="this.src='images/music-menu.png';"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: .75em;
    padding: 2px;
    z-index: 1; 
}

ul {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 8px solid black;
    border-width: 100%;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 4%;
}
```

Comment: Always load your own css ***after*** all library css. Last rule in takes precedence. So for example if something in a library stylesheet affects body, your `body` rule can over ride it

Comment: i tried but it didnt work. I tried placing my style css last and it still didnt work

Comment: I don't see you're using jquery anywhere in your code, so why not just remove it?

Comment: oh sorry i edited it, so you can now see the jquery being used

Answer (score 0):

Always load your own css ***after*** all library css.

Last rule loaded takes precedence.

So for example if something in a library stylesheet affects body, your body rule can over ride it.

jQuery UI for example will set some body styles such as font-size. If their rule loads after yours it would be the last loaded and take precedence.

For conflicts you need to inspect the offending elements in browser dev tools style inspector to see what specific rules are in effect and where they are located ( which file) for any element in the page. Then you can write adjustment rules in your stylesheet